# How to return a function component from a TypeScript function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was trying to write a function in my React Typescript project that returns a React function component but I got the error `BoxCard cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element`.

Boxcard.tsx

```js
import React, {
  useLayoutEffect,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
} from "react";

interface IBookingCode {
  bookingCode: string;
}

function BoxCard(bookingCode: IBookingCode) {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(null);

  return <div>{bookingCode.bookingCode}</div>;
}

export default BoxCard;
```

MainComponent.tsx

```js
import React, {
  useLayoutEffect,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
} from "react";
import BoxCard from "./Boxcard";

export const MainComponent = () => {
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
  const [bookingCode, setBookingCode] = useState<string>("");

  /*This function get the selected row from the DataTable component and set it in the selectedRow variable */

  const handleRowSelected = useCallback((state) => {
    setSelectedRows(state.selectedRows);
  }, []);

  /*This function picks the boxCode property from the selectedRow array/object variable*/
  const handleBoxCard = () => {
    selectedRows.map((r) => setBoxCode(r.boxCode));

    return <BoxCard boxCode={boxCode} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <button value="Open Component" onClick={handleBoxCard} />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Please note that I have only copied and showed the code that are concerned because the main file is big so I picked out the aspect that have to do with what I needed. I get the error

```js
BoxCard cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element
```

How do I return another function component from a React TypeScript function?

Comment: Can you include the definition of `BoxCard`, `selectedRows`, `boxCode`, and `setBoxCode`? There's no way for anyone to help you without a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're doing, but you should at least use `.forEach` instead of `.map` to avoid building an array you don't need and maybe just get the _last_ value from `selectedRows` rather than resetting the state multiple times in quick succession. Also note that `boxCode` will still be the closed-over value, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/3001761

Comment: My intention was to call up a functonal component from the function but it is not working.

Comment: Is your intention to **show** the `BoxCard` component when the button is clicked? If so you could add a new state something like `showBoxCards` then when the button is click the it to true and display all the boxcards

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do here.  Returning a value from an `onClick` handler won't render it.  You need to make use of state and conditional rendering.

Comment: I think all you need is this **inside the`return` statement** of the component? `{selectedRows.map((r) => <BoxCard key={r.boxCode} boxCode={r.boxCode} />)}` You use `boxCode` in some places and `bookingCode` in others so you need to fix that.